# CSS animation moves table row

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a simple gallery style page that has an image and when you roll over the image the dive expands to show some details.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjskujcy/) to show what I am trying to do (and the issue I'm having).

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/tjskujcy/]
```

When the mouse hovers the div expands like I want, but it moves the entire row below it down.

What I want to achieve is the dive to expand and only move the divs below it down - not the entire row.

I have put it in a table simply to keep all the divs at the top when hovered on. I couldn't get the divs on the same row to remain at the top with just CSS.

Is anyone able to help me with moving just the divs below the hovered one down? (Also not fussed on the table so if a CSS only solution will work I'll use it)

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Taking KittMedia's comment in to account - I removed the table.
http://jsfiddle.net/rwilkin/tjskujcy/4/  --  has 2 divs with three images in each 'row'

http://jsfiddle.net/rwilkin/tjskujcy/5/  --  1 div with 6 images

The issue is the same but also, the images on the same row move to the bottom of the row instead of staying put.

Comment: You cannot do it with a table layout. Additionally, do not use a table layout here. It is just outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback KittMedia, I was trying to avoid using a table but as I mentioned, I was having issues with CSS to keep the adjacent divs on the same row at the top of the div - they kept moving down when a div on the same row would expand.

Comment: You need to use columns, simple as - and javascript will most likely be involved - if you're ok with JS take a look at isotope masonry. If you absolutely don't want to use columns then you can clone the item absolute, and overlay it on the one beneath it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/0sgheqvf/1/).

I used `CSS3 flex-box` model, and think it addresses the problem with the row going down when an item from the top row expands. Though here are some problems (I'm not sure if these are fine with you):

- Not using tables
- Layout is columnar instead of by rows
- The item order is from top to bottom then left to right
- The container height must be fixed (so that columns will exist)

More on CSS3 Flex-box [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thank you KiiroSora the only problem with this is the fixed height, but with a little php magic I should be able to sort that out. The item order and columnar layout aren't an issue and not using a table is a better option (the only reason I did was to keep the row fixed in place).

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of jquery I got this *almost* like you wanted, kinda hackish but ok:

```
$("div#outer").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().attr("rowspan", "2");
});
```

Have a look at the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjskujcy/3/)

Comment: It is close, thank you. I'll have a play with js and see if I can use it to get what I want.

Comment: I'd suggest you clone the element right below it into the same `<tr>` to cover up for the white space when expanding. And then remove the cloned element again when the size of `#outer` reaches its initial height again.